# Horizontal scroll view scrolling one item at time

Tags: java, android

i am currently implementing a panel that include horizontal list view using Horizontal scroll view . in that I need control the scrolling of Horizontal scroll view and do the scrolling one item at time.

could any one give me idea to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding. It sounds like you are trying to make HorizontalScrollView behave in the same way that [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) behaves. If that is the case do you have a specific reason that you aren't using the ViewPager instead?

Comment: thank you.I have checked ViewPager  but it seems we can not connect that to adapter .i have dynamic records so my solution must have adapter .

Comment: Well, do you want to make the scroll programmatically? If so, when do you want to do it? Or when the user scrolls the view you just want to scroll one item at a time? In this case is not a recommended way, the user may scroll as much as she/he likes.

Comment: But it is the requirement i got so i have to implement that some how :).i want to control the scrolling to one item  at time now when you Scroll it goes to couple of items.

Comment: ViewPager definitely does use an Adapter. see here: [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html)

Comment: Yes. But i need a  horizontal list to act as a ViewPager  in my solution due to requirement . i have started working on this my self and i am almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to do this using overriding HorizontalScrollView and merging code i got from various internet examples .it is working fine .

i have used gestureDetector and onFling method to achieve this task.

```
public void setCenter(int index) {

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

    View preView = parent.getChildAt(prevIndex);
    //preView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#64CBD8"));
    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);
    preView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    View view = parent.getChildAt(index);
    //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    int screenWidth = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    int scrollX = (view.getLeft() - (screenWidth / 2))
            + (view.getWidth() / 2);
    this.smoothScrollTo(scrollX, 0);
    prevIndex = index;
    Log.d("ITEM", String.valueOf(prevIndex));
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    if (flingDisable)
        return false;
    boolean returnValue = false;
    float ptx1 = 0, ptx2 = 0;
    if (e1 == null || e2 == null)
        return false;
    ptx1 = e1.getX();
    ptx2 = e2.getX();
    // right to left

    if (ptx1 - ptx2 > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
        if (activeItem < maxItem - 1)
            activeItem = activeItem + 1;

        returnValue = true;

    } else if (ptx2 - ptx1 > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
        if (activeItem > 0)
            activeItem = activeItem - 1;

        returnValue = true;
    }
    //scrollTo = activeItem * itemWidth;
    //this.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollTo);
    setCenter(activeItem);
    return returnValue;
}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }
    Boolean returnValue = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    int x = (int) event.getRawX();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (start) {
            this.prevScrollX = x;
            start = false;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        start = true;
        this.currentScrollX = x;
        int minFactor = itemWidth / SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR;

        if ((this.prevScrollX - this.currentScrollX) > minFactor) {
            if (activeItem < maxItem - 1)
                activeItem = activeItem + 1;

        } else if ((this.currentScrollX - this.prevScrollX) > minFactor) {
            if (activeItem > 0)
                activeItem = activeItem - 1;
        }
        Log.d("ITEM", String.valueOf(activeItem));
        setCenter(activeItem);
        returnValue = true;
        break;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: hello brother ! i am also suffering from this problem will you provide me full code example. ???? ASP

Comment: Yes i can sent you the main class let me know how can i send that.